# Is there a way to add custom (not taxonomy) attributes and variations to Wocommerce 7.5.1 Variable product?

Tags: woocommerce

I want to add not taxonomy attributes and variations to a Woocommerce 7.5.1 variable product programmatically.

When done, the result in frontend is that i can see the attributes for the product, but when one is selected, point to the wrong variation and always the same variation.

In the backend, when the product is edited i can see the correct attributes and the variations but with no value selected. When i try to select the correct value for each variation the rest of variations values are missed. I can not assign its correct values.

When this is done not programmatically, it works. I can not figure what is happening.

this is a piece of my code that causes what early described:

```
// **** Product Object and its properties
$obProducto=new WC_Product_Variable();
$obProducto->set_sku('SOME_SKU');
$obProducto->set_name('Some Title');
$obProducto->set_short_description('Some short description');
$obProducto->set_description('Some long description');
$obProducto->set_regular_price('99,99');
$obProducto->set_sale_price('59,99');
$obProducto->set_manage_stock(true);
$obProducto->set_sold_individually(true);
$obProducto->set_backorders('no');
$obProducto->set_stock_status('instock');
$obProducto->set_stock_quantity('1500');
$obProducto->set_low_stock_amount('50');

// **** Attribute to be assigned to the product object
$attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
$attribute->set_id(0);
$attribute->set_name( 'ContenidoNeto' );
$attribute->set_options( array( '100ml', '200ml' ) );
$attribute->set_position( 1 );
$attribute->set_visible( 1 );
$attribute->set_variation( 1 );
$attributes[] = $attribute;
$obProducto->set_attributes( $attributes );
$obProducto->save();

// **** The two variations
$variation1 = new WC_Product_Variation();
$variation1->set_parent_id( $obProducto->get_id() );
$variation1->save();
$variation1->set_attributes( array( 'ContenidoNeto' => '100ml' ) );
$variation1->set_regular_price( 9999.99 );
$variation1->save();

$variation2 = new WC_Product_Variation();
$variation2->set_parent_id( $obProducto->get_id() );
$variation2->save();
$variation2->set_attributes( array( 'ContenidoNeto' => '200ml' ) );
$variation2->set_regular_price( 8888.88 );
$variation2->save();
```

Comment: New Observations: Compared print_r of objects.

Comment: 1) Manually created object with programmatically created object raise that name of second is the same as parent (same for all variations). Is this the problem?. All variations with the same name?

2) Programmatically created object in memory with it self recovered from BBDD with wc_get_product($nId): Name is correct (parent_title+variation_value) in memory, but after BBDD Name is incorrect (parent_title). Maybe is this the problem?

Comment: 3) Attribute Name associated with variation remains after BBDD but not its associated value.

Answer (score 0):

After many wasted time ... **Attribute names must be lowercase.**

```
'ContenidoNeto' //Wrong
'contenidoneto' //Right
```